# The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user

Tags: entity-framework, validación, login

Muy buenas. Tengo un problema con el Anti-Forgery con un caso un poco particular:

1.- Introduzco incorrectamente la contraseña.
2.- Introduzco correctamente usuario y contraseña.
3.- Voy hacia atrás en el historial.
4.- Introduzca lo que introduzca me da el error *"The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user."*

Si eliminamos el punto 1 y volvemos atras, puedo loguearme sin problema. Es decir, hay algo en el paso por el error del login.

```cs
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        Log.DEBUG(ConstLog.ENTRA_METODO + this.GetType().Name + "." + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        Session.RemoveAll();
        // ViewBag.ReturnUrl =  returnUrl;
        Log.DEBUG(ConstLog.SALE_METODO + this.GetType().Name + "." + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.DEBUG(ConstLog.ENTRA_METODO + this.GetType().Name + "." + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Log.DEBUG(ConstLog.SALE_METODO + this.GetType().Name + "." + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                return View(model);
            }

            ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, false,/*model.RememberMe,*/ false);

                UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
                userDTO.IdUser = user.Id;
                userDTO.Nombre = user.Nombre;
                userDTO.Apellidos = user.Apellidos;
                SetAuditoria(userDTO, ConstAudit.ACTION_LOGIN, String.Format(ConstAudit.LOGIN_USER, userDTO.Nombre, userDTO.Apellidos));

                Session["NombreUsuario"] = user.Nombre + " " + user.Apellidos;
                Session["IdUsusario"] = user.Id;

                Log.DEBUG(ConstLog.SALE_METODO + this.GetType().Name + "." + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

            }
            else
            {
                Log.DEBUG(ConstLog.SALE_METODO + this.GetType().Name + "." + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Contraseña incorrecta");
                return View(model);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.DEBUG(ConstLog.EXCEPCION + this.GetType().Name + "." + ex.InnerException);                    
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Para empezar a buscar la causa del problema, te recomiendo que a tu petición HTTPGET le quites el atributo `OutputCache` y ensayes nuevamente. Ahora bien, para utilizar `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` en tu petición POST debes asegurar que tu vista tenga incluida la siguiente instrucción `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`.

Comment: Eliminar el OutputCache lo probé pero sigue dando el mismo error. De hecho el OutputCache es necesario para que, si vas hacia atrás, la página se recargue ya que obligo a la aplicación a pasar por el GET.

Y con respecto a @Html.AntiForgeryToken(), lo tengo puesto en la vista. De hecho está puesto en todas las vistas (cosa que probablemente no sea necesaria).